# walkdir how to find group of file types

Tags: file, rust, closures

```
pub fn get_files(path: String)   {
for entry in WalkDir::new(path).into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()){
    if entry.file_type().is_file() {
        if entry.path().display().to_string().ends_with(".mp3"){
            println!("{}",entry.path().display());
        }
    }
}}
```

hi guys i use this function to check for the available mp3 files in given folder. now i need to check the mp3 and flac files. rather than using if else how can i achieve this?.

Comment: `if entry.path().extension() == Some (&OsStr::new ("mp3")) or entry.path().extension() == Some (&OsStr::new ("flac"))`?

Comment: If you are working on a filesystem where you know all file names are valid UTF8, you can also use a match instead of `if else`

Comment: how can i implement match for this. i'm bit confused

Comment: Nitpicks: Don't use `to_string()` if `to_str()` would work as well. If you already have a `Path` object, use its `.extension()` method directly instead of weirdly converting into a String and then matching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things I would change:

- Use `.extension()` instead of weirdly converting into a string and then matching that with `.ends_with()`
- Use `match` if you want to handle multiple endings
- Don't use `String` as a parameter - use `&str` instead. It is almost always better and more general.
- In fact, the ideal API doesn't use `String` or `&str` - it uses `AsRef<Path>`, as can also be seen in the [std library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) and [WalkDir](https://docs.rs/walkdir/latest/walkdir/struct.WalkDir.html#method.new).

```rust
use std::{ffi::OsStr, path::Path};

use walkdir::WalkDir;

pub fn get_files(path: impl AsRef<Path>) {
    for entry in WalkDir::new(path).into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
        if entry.file_type().is_file() {
            let path = entry.path();
            if let Some(extension) = path.extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str) {
                match extension {
                    "mp3" => println!("MP3: {}", path.display()),
                    "flac" => println!("FLAC: {}", path.display()),
                    _ => (),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you dislike the `if let Some` followed by `match`, you can also combine them. Which one you choose is personal preference.

```rust
use std::{ffi::OsStr, path::Path};

use walkdir::WalkDir;

pub fn get_files(path: impl AsRef<Path>) {
    for entry in WalkDir::new(path).into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
        if entry.file_type().is_file() {
            let path = entry.path();
            match path.extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str) {
                Some("mp3") => println!("MP3: {}", path.display()),
                Some("flac") => println!("FLAC: {}", path.display()),
                _ => (),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference using String and &str in parameters?

Comment: @devMe `String` is owned - you will destroy the object where the string comes from, forcing a `.clone()` somewhere. `&String` is better, because it doesn't destroy the original object, but won't take `"bla.txt"` literals. `&str` is the same as `&String`, just that it also accepts literals. And `impl AsRef<Path>` accepts all of the above plus also `Path` objects. In parameters, always be as permissive as possible.